# Can't access array elements

Tags: c#, arrays

This is an excerpt from a script for a simple card game I'm making. But I'm not very good with arrays and for some reason I can't get it to work. It keeps replying with

> Cannot convert method group 'Draw' to non-delegate type 'int'.

I've looked around but can't seem to find an answer. If you need the rest of the code for context I can post it.

```
// Generates three cards with two random values on each then 
stores them inside the usercardvalues array 



    int[] UserCardValues = new int[3] {PlayDeck.Draw, PlayDeck.Draw, PlayDeck.Draw};
    Console.WriteLine(UserName + "'s Damage / Health values are");                                                                                                 
    Console.WriteLine("Card 1: {0}", UserCardValues[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("Card 2: {0}", UserCardValues[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Card 3: {0}", UserCardValues[2]);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue!");
    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    Console.ReadLine();

// Gets and prints the dealers card from the random generator
    int[] DealerCardValues = new int[3] {PlayDeck.Draw, PlayDeck.Draw, PlayDeck.Draw}; 
    Console.WriteLine("The Dealers Damage / Health Values are");
    Console.WriteLine("Card 1: {0}", DealerCardValues[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("Card 2: {0}", DealerCardValues[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Card 3: {0}", DealerCardValues[2]);                                         
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue!");
    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is `Draw` a method? And does it return an `int`?

Comment: If yes, then `Draw()`

Comment: Error message says what the issue is :)

Comment: `Object.Method` gives a reference to the method.  `Object.Method()` executes `Method` and returns its return value.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Draw` is a method, and that's pretty obvious by the error, you should be using it *like a method:*

```
PlayDeck.Draw()
```

and not like:

```
PlayDeck.Draw
```

But *do remember*, `Draw()` needs to `return` and `int`.